# Set default font for SWT Shell

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

Is there a way to set a default font for the whole Shell such that any new control will use that same font?

It seems that right now I have to set the font for every control I create, which leads to too much redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font which is used by default is chosen by platform (see other info in [Class Font - SWT: The Standard Widget Toolkit](http://book.javanb.com/swt-the-standard-widget-toolkit/ch18lev1sec2.html)), so it's not possible to set default font for all widgets, if you want that, you have to do it "by hand"..

Why are you changing default font anyway..?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but I was interested in changing the font _size_. The default one is too small and I'd like to have a pref that lets me modify it at will for the whole application.

Comment: I'm afraid, that it's the same thing.. In SWT you set font size by setting new font, with different size..

Answer (score 0):

There was not an api to change the default font size.

However, we could use **class shadowing** side effect to do that. For example (osx), duplicated a source code **org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSFont** and update the method

```
public static NSFont systemFontOfSize(double fontSize) {
    // hacking it by class shadowing
    fontSize = 24;
    long result = OS.objc_msgSend(OS.class_NSFont, OS.sel_systemFontOfSize_, fontSize);
    return result != 0 ? new NSFont(result) : null;
}
```

We re-assign a bigger font size before SWT get the result

[image: My Bigger Font Window]

It is hacking, not recommended using at the production evnironment.