# How to change SWT default font size?

Tags: java, swt

https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet100.java

I found a snippet to change the font size of a label, however, were it possible to change the default font size.

I want to make it bigger than default, because the application was used by older people for now.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220643/set-default-font-for-swt-shell

Comment: The default size is just whatever the native controls that SWT uses have as the default - so this is set by the operating system not SWT. An Eclipse e4 RCP can use CSS to set sizes, but that isn't available in the base SWT.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 give me an idea. I find the source and see how does it set the default font. There was a set of bridge class between OS and SWT. It could be done by class shadowing like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62857294/90909